# Error when first trying to compile Open-CV using CMake

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake

I am new on Open-CV, and would like to compile the project.

First thing, was to download the code, and after that, compile using CMake.

To reproduce my problem, just download open-CV from oficial webpage.
https://opencv.org/releases/

- OpenCV – 4.4.0

When Trying to compile using CMake. I selected Generator  "Visual Studio 16 2019", which is the version of visual studio that i have installed in my computer.

I got an error.

Could someone give me any advice on how to solve or debug this problem?

I am locked not sure how to solve it

See content of  CMakeError.txt

```
Determining if the function fseeko exists failed with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/opencv-4.4.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe cmTC_c9237.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /p:VisualStudioVersion=16.0 /v:m && Microsoft(R) Build Engine versÆo 16.6.0+5ff7b0c9e para .NET Framework 

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Todos os direitos reservados.



  Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler VersÆo 19.26.28806 para x64

  CheckFunctionExists.c

  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Todos os direitos reservados.

  cl /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:column /MP /Od /Ob0 /Oi /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D CHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=fseeko /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /Gy /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"cmTC_c9237.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_c9237.dir\Debug\vc142.pdb" /Gd /TC /errorReport:queue  /bigobj "C:\Program Files\CMake\share\cmake-3.18\Modules\CheckFunctionExists.c"

CheckFunctionExists.obj : error LNK2019: s¡mbolo externo nÆo resolvido, fseeko, referenciado na fun‡Æo main [C:\opencv-4.4.0\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_c9237.vcxproj]

C:\opencv-4.4.0\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\cmTC_c9237.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 externo nÆo resolvidos [C:\opencv-4.4.0\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_c9237.vcxproj]




Determining size of off64_t failed with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/opencv-4.4.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe cmTC_86805.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /p:VisualStudioVersion=16.0 /v:m && Microsoft(R) Build Engine versÆo 16.6.0+5ff7b0c9e para .NET Framework 

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Todos os direitos reservados.



  Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler VersÆo 19.26.28806 para x64

  OFF64_T.c

  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Todos os direitos reservados.

  cl /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:column /MP /Od /Ob0 /Oi /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /Gy /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"cmTC_86805.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_86805.dir\Debug\vc142.pdb" /Gd /TC /errorReport:queue  /bigobj "C:\opencv-4.4.0\build\CMakeFiles\CheckTypeSize\OFF64_T.c"

C:\opencv-4.4.0\build\CMakeFiles\CheckTypeSize\OFF64_T.c(29,12): error C2065: 'off64_t': identificador nÆo declarado [C:\opencv-4.4.0\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_86805.vcxproj]

C:\opencv-4.4.0\build\CMakeFiles\CheckTypeSize\OFF64_T.c(30,12): error C2065: 'off64_t': identificador nÆo declarado [C:\opencv-4.4.0\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_86805.vcxproj]

C:\opencv-4.4.0\build\CMakeFiles\CheckTypeSize\OFF64_T.c(31,12): error C2065: 'off64_t': identificador nÆo declarado [C:\opencv-4.4.0\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_86805.vcxproj]

C:\opencv-4.4.0\build\CMakeFiles\CheckTypeSize\OFF64_T.c(32,12): error C2065: 'off64_t': identificador nÆo declarado [C:\opencv-4.4.0\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_86805.vcxproj]

C:\opencv-4.4.0\build\CMakeFiles\CheckTypeSize\OFF64_T.c(33,12): error C2065: 'off64_t': identificador nÆo declarado [C:\opencv-4.4.0\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_86805.vcxproj]



C:/opencv-4.4.0/build/CMakeFiles/CheckTypeSize/OFF64_T.c:
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>


#undef KEY
#if defined(__i386)
# define KEY '_','_','i','3','8','6'
#elif defined(__x86_64)
# define KEY '_','_','x','8','6','_','6','4'
#elif defined(__PPC64__)
# define KEY '_','_','P','P','C','6','4','_','_'
#elif defined(__ppc64__)
# define KEY '_','_','p','p','c','6','4','_','_'
#elif defined(__PPC__)
# define KEY '_','_','P','P','C','_','_'
#elif defined(__ppc__)
# define KEY '_','_','p','p','c','_','_'
#elif defined(__aarch64__)
# define KEY '_','_','a','a','r','c','h','6','4','_','_'
#elif defined(__ARM_ARCH_7A__)
# define KEY '_','_','A','R','M','_','A','R','C','H','_','7','A','_','_'
#elif defined(__ARM_ARCH_7S__)
# define KEY '_','_','A','R','M','_','A','R','C','H','_','7','S','_','_'
#endif

#define SIZE (sizeof(off64_t))
static char info_size[] =  {'I', 'N', 'F', 'O', ':', 's','i','z','e','[',
  ('0' + ((SIZE / 10000)%10)),
  ('0' + ((SIZE / 1000)%10)),
  ('0' + ((SIZE / 100)%10)),
  ('0' + ((SIZE / 10)%10)),
  ('0' +  (SIZE    % 10)),
  ']',
#ifdef KEY
  ' ','k','e','y','[', KEY, ']',
#endif
  '\0'};

#ifdef __CLASSIC_C__
int main(argc, argv) int argc; char *argv[];
#else
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
#endif
{
  int require = 0;
  require += info_size[argc];
  (void)argv;
  return require;
}


Determining if the function memmove exists failed with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/opencv-4.4.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe cmTC_210f4.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /p:VisualStudioVersion=16.0 /v:m && Microsoft(R) Build Engine versÆo 16.6.0+5ff7b0c9e para .NET Framework 

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Todos os direitos reservados.



  Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler VersÆo 19.26.28806 para x64

  CheckFunctionExists.c

  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Todos os direitos reservados.

  cl /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:column /MP /Od /Ob0 /Oi /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D CHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=memmove /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /Gy /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"cmTC_210f4.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_210f4.dir\Debug\vc142.pdb" /Gd /TC /errorReport:queue  /bigobj "C:\Program Files\CMake\share\cmake-3.18\Modules\CheckFunctionExists.c"

C:\Program Files\CMake\share\cmake-3.18\Modules\CheckFunctionExists.c(7,3): warning C4391: 'char memmove(void)': tipo de retorno incorreto para fun‡Æo intr¡nseca, esperado 'void' [C:\opencv-4.4.0\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_210f4.vcxproj]

C:\Program Files\CMake\share\cmake-3.18\Modules\CheckFunctionExists.c(7,3): warning C4392: 'char memmove(void)': n£mero de argumentos incorreto para fun‡Æo intr¡nseca, esperados '3' argumentos [C:\opencv-4.4.0\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_210f4.vcxproj]

C:\Program Files\CMake\share\cmake-3.18\Modules\CheckFunctionExists.c(17,25): error C2168: 'memmove': poucos parƒmetros reais para fun‡Æo intr¡nseca [C:\opencv-4.4.0\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_210f4.vcxproj]




Determining if the function strcasecmp exists failed with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/opencv-4.4.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe cmTC_ec25b.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /p:VisualStudioVersion=16.0 /v:m && Microsoft(R) Build Engine versÆo 16.6.0+5ff7b0c9e para .NET Framework 

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Todos os direitos reservados.



  Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler VersÆo 19.26.28806 para x64

  CheckFunctionExists.c

  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Todos os direitos reservados.

  cl /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:column /MP /Od /Ob0 /Oi /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D CHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=strcasecmp /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /Gy /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"cmTC_ec25b.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_ec25b.dir\Debug\vc142.pdb" /Gd /TC /errorReport:queue  /bigobj "C:\Program Files\CMake\share\cmake-3.18\Modules\CheckFunctionExists.c"

CheckFunctionExists.obj : error LNK2019: s¡mbolo externo nÆo resolvido, strcasecmp, referenciado na fun‡Æo main [C:\opencv-4.4.0\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_ec25b.vcxproj]

C:\opencv-4.4.0\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\cmTC_ec25b.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 externo nÆo resolvidos [C:\opencv-4.4.0\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_ec25b.vcxproj]




Build output check failed:
    Regex: 'warning D9002'
    Output line: 'cl : linha de comando warning D9002: ignorando op‡Æo desconhecida '-std=c99' [C:\opencv-4.4.0\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_87690.vcxproj]
'
Compilation failed:
    source file: 'C:/opencv-4.4.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/src.c'
    check option: ' /DWIN32 /D_WINDOWS /W3  /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /Gy /bigobj /Oi  /fp:precise     /MP -std=c99'
===== BUILD LOG =====
Change Dir: C:/opencv-4.4.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe cmTC_87690.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /p:VisualStudioVersion=16.0 /v:m && Microsoft(R) Build Engine versÆo 16.6.0+5ff7b0c9e para .NET Framework 

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Todos os direitos reservados.



  Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler VersÆo 19.26.28806 para x64

  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Todos os direitos reservados.

  cl /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:column /MP /Od /Ob0 /Oi /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /Gy /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"cmTC_87690.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_87690.dir\Debug\vc142.pdb" /Gd /TC /errorReport:queue  /bigobj /bigobj -std=c99 "C:\opencv-4.4.0\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\src.c"

cl : linha de comando warning D9002: ignorando op‡Æo desconhecida '-std=c99' [C:\opencv-4.4.0\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_87690.vcxproj]

  src.c

  cmTC_87690.vcxproj -> C:\opencv-4.4.0\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\cmTC_87690.exe



===== END =====

Determining if the function sgemm_ exists failed with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/opencv-4.4.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe cmTC_02923.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /p:VisualStudioVersion=16.0 /v:m && Microsoft(R) Build Engine versÆo 16.6.0+5ff7b0c9e para .NET Framework 

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Todos os direitos reservados.



  Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler VersÆo 19.26.28806 para x64

  CheckFunctionExists.c

  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Todos os direitos reservados.

  cl /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:column /MP /Od /Ob0 /Oi /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D CHECK_FUNCTION_EXISTS=sgemm_ /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /Gy /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"cmTC_02923.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_02923.dir\Debug\vc142.pdb" /Gd /TC /errorReport:queue  /bigobj "C:\Program Files\CMake\share\cmake-3.18\Modules\CheckFunctionExists.c"

CheckFunctionExists.obj : error LNK2019: s¡mbolo externo nÆo resolvido, sgemm_, referenciado na fun‡Æo main [C:\opencv-4.4.0\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_02923.vcxproj]

C:\opencv-4.4.0\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\Debug\cmTC_02923.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 externo nÆo resolvidos [C:\opencv-4.4.0\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_02923.vcxproj]




Determining if the include file pthread.h exists failed with the following output:
Change Dir: C:/opencv-4.4.0/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

Run Build Command(s):C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/MSBuild/Current/Bin/MSBuild.exe cmTC_d3745.vcxproj /p:Configuration=Debug /p:Platform=x64 /p:VisualStudioVersion=16.0 /v:m && Microsoft(R) Build Engine versÆo 16.6.0+5ff7b0c9e para .NET Framework 

Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Todos os direitos reservados.



  Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler VersÆo 19.26.28806 para x64

  CheckIncludeFile.c

  Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. Todos os direitos reservados.

  cl /c /Zi /W3 /WX- /diagnostics:column /MP /Od /Ob0 /Oi /D WIN32 /D _WINDOWS /D _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D _CRT_NONSTDC_NO_DEPRECATE /D _SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D "CMAKE_INTDIR=\"Debug\"" /D _MBCS /Gm- /RTC1 /MDd /GS /Gy /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Zc:inline /Fo"cmTC_d3745.dir\Debug\\" /Fd"cmTC_d3745.dir\Debug\vc142.pdb" /Gd /TC /errorReport:queue  /bigobj "C:\opencv-4.4.0\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\CheckIncludeFile.c"

C:\opencv-4.4.0\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\CheckIncludeFile.c(1,10): fatal error C1083: NÆo ‚ poss¡vel abrir arquivo incluir: 'pthread.h': No such file or directory [C:\opencv-4.4.0\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\cmTC_d3745.vcxproj]
```

Comment: "I got an error." - Show that error, not the content of `CMakeError.txt`.

Comment: The content is in the code block

Comment: No, you seem don't understand: the error message is contained in the **configuration log** (or **output**), above the lines "Configuring incomplete, errors occured!". Scroll up the output log and find the first error message in it. The file `CMakeError.txt` doesn't contain that error message, and that file is mostly not relevant to the problem.